# Fix link to Ubuntu Leadership Conduct

Tags: bug

Currently, in our [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service), we have the following paragraph

> When accessing the askubuntu.com, meta.askubuntu.com, or chat.askubuntu.com sites ("AskUbuntu"), Subscriber will also abide by the Ubuntu Code of Conduct, which can be found at http://www.ubuntu.com/community/conduct, and is hereby incorporated by reference, but solely with regard to AskUbuntu. Subscribers with moderator privileges on AskUbuntu agree to abide by the Ubuntu Leadership Code of Conduct, which can be found at http://www.ubuntu.com/community/leadership-conduct, and is hereby incorporated by reference, but solely with regard to moderators on AskUbuntu.

Unfortunately, the Leadership Conduct link (http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/leadership-conduct) is a broken link, and [apparently everything is contained in the new code of conduct](https://askubuntu.com/q/250991/69210). Could the ToS be updated to include this?

Comment: This should happen. However, that TOS is managed by the legal department of Stack Exchange, so we'll hear from them when they weigh in

Comment: @MarcoCeppi: I know -- I initially was going to post this on MSO (migrate if you wish though, it sorta makes more sense there)

Comment: The team should see it here, no need to really migrate imo

Comment: @MarcoCeppi: k, np :)

Comment: I'll get this looked into. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. Changes have been submitted to the devs; I'll update this answer once they're in production.

EDIT:  Changes are now live on the ToS - single url goes to the unified ToS.